# Pass success callback function with arguments to another function that performs AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to javascript and trying to understand if following thing is possible:

Let's say I use following ajax request construction in several places in my code (with different success callback functions - in this example only `handleSuccessCallback()`) and different url and data request param:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: loadUrl,
        data: data,
        error: errorCallback,
        success: function(response) {
            this.handleSuccessCallback(response);
        }
    }); 

function handleSuccessCallback(response) {
     Do something with response here...
}
```

I wanted to refactor this code in such way, that I don't need to create construction above each time I need to send request. I wanted to create a function in my utils class that will take url, request data and error/success callback. Something like this:

```
 function sendAjaxRequest(url, data, errorCallback, successCallback)
  jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        error: errorCallback,
        success: successCallback
  }); 
 }
```

Then, I wanted to call this function several times passing different arguments from my main script.

In my main code:

```
var url = "https://some url";
var data = {};
var errorCallback = handleErrorCallback();
var successCallback = handleSuccessCallback(); // ??? This function requires `response` argument being passed, how it can be done?

utils.sendAjaxRequest(url, data, errorCallback, successCallback);


function handleSuccessCallback(response) {
     Do something with response here...
}

function handleErrorCallback() {
     Do something with error here...
}
```

However, what I don't understanding is the following: 
how can I pass success callback function (`handleSuccessCallback(response)`) to the `sendAjaxRequest()` function, if my `handleSuccessCallback(response)` needs params which is result of the success ajax callback itself(`response`)?

How can I pass this `response` param to `handleSuccessCallback()` when passing it to `sendAjaxRequest()` if I don't know yet what will be the `response` from ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to call:

```
function sendAjaxRequest(url, data, errorCallback, successCallback)
```

You just need to give names of functions for `errorCallback` and `successCallback`. You are passing function references, so they can be called by other code. The params are provided at the point where those functions are called, like in your original example:

```
success: function(response) {
        this.handleSuccessCallback(response);
    }
```

Here the success function as defined in `ajax` with first parameter as `response`, so you have an anonymous function here with the first parameter as `response`.

So you just need to define your functions to match what they will be when they get called by `ajax`, e.g.:

```
var firstSuccessCallback = function(response) {
    //do something;
}

var firstErrorCallback = function(error) {
    //do something;
}
```

you can do:

```
sendAjaxRequest(url, data, firstErrorCallback, firstSuccessCallback)
```